# Select Top 1 based on distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to select the `top 1` record from each group of column `UnitID` and `CompanyCode` and using order by from column `CreatedDate`

Here's an example of my table

```
ID | UnitID | CompanyCode | CreatedDate |
----------------------------------------|
1  |   A1   |    G100     | 2020-03-12  |
2  |   A1   |    G100     | 2020-03-13  |
3  |   A1   |    G100     | 2020-03-14  |
4  |   B2   |    G100     | 2020-03-12  |
5  |   B2   |    F200     | 2020-03-13  |
6  |   B2   |    E300     | 2020-03-14  |
```

My expected results would be these rows

```
ID | UnitID | CompanyCode | CreatedDate |
----------------------------------------|
3  |   A1   |    G100     | 2020-03-14  |
4  |   B2   |    G100     | 2020-03-12  |
5  |   B2   |    F200     | 2020-03-13  |
6  |   B2   |    E300     | 2020-03-14  |
```

We looking at UnitID first, next check CompanyCode If there is a record with different `CompanyCode` it will be display, but if have same, it will be select top 1 with order by createdDate

SIMPLE QUERY: `SELECT ID, UnitID, CompanyCode, CreatedDate FROM Tbl_Unit ORDER BY CreatedDate`

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: What if there's a tie, i.e. two records with the same `unitid`, `companycode` and `createddate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the next statement may help:

```
SELECT ID, UnitID, CompanyCode, CreatedDate
FROM (
   SELECT 
      ID, UnitID, CompanyCode, CreatedDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitID, CompanyCode ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS Rn
   FROM Tbl_Unit
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I like using `TOP 1 WITH TIES` for handling this type of query on SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM Tbl_Unit
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitID, CompanyCode ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` Function.

```
 SELECT ID  , UnitID ,  CompanyCode ,  CreatedDate FROM 
 (
 select TAB.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId , CompanyCode order by  createddate desc )  RNK from TAB
  ) Drived WHERE RNK=1;
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/QQMJ63523)

```
ROW_NUMBER() -- Funtion to generate row number
 OVER (PARTITION BY UnitId , CompanyCode  --  Partition range 
order by  createddate desc -- Sorting order )
```